# Restore database with Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, restore, high-availability

I have high availability enabled with two servers and when trying to restore a database I realised I had to un-synchronize the database and then remove it from the availability group.

I use Ola Hallagrens maintenance solution. Is there something I can amend with Ola's script to automatically remove DB from availability group when I run the restore job or is there a script already available, or simply not do-able?

Thanks

Comment: How are you restoring a DB using Ola's scripts?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to revise your question with clarity:

Olas scripts meant for following, not for restoring database.

1. [Backup](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)
2. [DBCC - Integrity Check](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html)
3. [Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) - Index and Statistics

Aside from this, you cannot DROP or RESTORE a database while it's part of Availability Group. You can remove a database from availability group with following commands:

PRIMARY Replica:

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP AGName remove database DatabaseName;
```

SECONDARY Replica:

```
ALTER database DatabaseName set HADR OFF;
```